# Android Studio manifest Errors

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Could anyone please me as when ever I try to run my app I get errors in the manifest file such as the followig five errors below.

Error:(2) No resource identifier found for attribute 'versioncode' in package 'android'

Error:(2) No resource identifier found for attribute 'versionname' in package 'android'

Error:(9) No resource identifier found for attribute 'minsdkversion' in package 'android'

Error:(9) No resource identifier found for attribute 'targetsdkversion' in package 'android'

I have posted my code below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest android:versioncode="1" android:versionname="1.0" package="com.brad.visor" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<uses-sdk android:minsdkversion="9" android:targetsdkversion="17">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/logo" android:label="@string/app_name">

        <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Login"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Register"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Registered"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".PasswordReset"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ChangePassword"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>

</application>
<!-- Allow to connect with internet and to know the current network state-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE">

    </uses-permission></uses-permission></uses-sdk></manifest>
```

Comment: <manifest android:versioncode="1" android:versionname="1.0" package="com.brad.visor" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-sdk android:minsdkversion="9" android:targetsdkversion="17">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because I believe your manifest is simply incorrect. Your manifest should look something like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="location" >

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".OtherActivity">
    </activity>
  </application>

</manifest>
```

Your version information is located in your `build.gradle` of your project (Should say something like `(Module: app)` next to the build.).

Comment: Hi Rose,I am still getting the same errors, I have tried to clean the project which has not helped me aswell.please help.

Comment: Hello, did you try to make the code look like the above manifest? You should remove `uses-sdk` tag, for clarification. You should also move your permissions inside the manifest tag and make sure you remove `android:versioncode="1" android:versionname="1.0"` parameters from the manifest tag.

Comment: Thank You Rose it is now working and can run, I need to include <!-- Allow to connect with internet and to know the current network state-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE">

    </uses-permission></uses-permission></uses-sdk></manifest>

Comment: could you tell me how I can make it run with the above created so I want the application to connect to the internet and to check or know the current network state.

Comment: You just need to include `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` and `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />` inside your manifest. Kill the `</uses-permission>` as you have those nested in such a way that it will cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

There is mistake in your Manifest files. Its case sensitive.

Use it like this

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx.yyy.zzz"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

You have used all lower case letters.Like this

```
**<uses-sdk android:minsdkversion="9" android:targetsdkversion="17">**
```

Changing this as mentioned will fix your errors